# How to create a stored procedure from EF Core code first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

In EF Core, we can add the tables using entity classes. Stored procedure is one of the useful component. So is there any way to create a stored procedure from the `DbContext` class (just like Using Dbset we can create the tables)?

Have gone through some links where in the EF6 there is a way to push the stored procedure, although its an workaround it seems.

Reference Link--> [EF 6 code-first with custom stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301964/ef-6-code-first-with-custom-stored-procedure)

Although I followed the above link, it means for EF6, where the migration files were inherited from `DbMigration`, in EF Core it's a `Migration` base class. I don't see a way & probably didn't find much article related to it.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Hi @lokanath das, any update about this case?

Comment: Not yet, still looking for some approach... as this is a workaround but not the exact solution that we can rely on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, we use `MigrationBuilder.Sql` method in the `Up` method of your `migration` class to create a stored procedure, like below:

```
public partial class SPCreate : Migration
{
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    //...

    var sp = @"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudents]
        AS
        BEGIN
            select * from Students
        END";

    migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    //...
}
}
```

To execute a stored procedure, you can call `FromSqlRaw` method, like this:

```
var students= _dbcontext.Students.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE GetStudents").ToList();
```

Comment: In this case,First we need to run the Add-Migration Command, then this Up & Down Methods will come, this is more or less like Workaround i think. As i mentioned , is there a compact way just like we add the Dbset for Tables?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such method.

Comment: I too didn't get much content related to this.

Comment: Generally use code first is to use a method like mine.

Comment: what if we need procedure for different datatype that is not in Dataset?

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class SPCreate : Migration
{
   protected override void Up()
   {
       Sql(@"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudents]
          AS
          BEGIN
              select * from Students
          END");
    }

    protected override void Down()
    {
  
    }
}
//Calling on code 
List<Customer> list;
string sql = "EXEC GetStudents";
list = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Student>(sql).ToList();


List();
```

Answer (score -1):

Like the normal situation add a migration with a command like bellow:

> Add-Migration "Migration Name"

Then in the Up section add as follows:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().
        Where(str => str.EndsWith(".sql"));
    foreach (string resourceName in resourceNames)
    {
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string sql = reader.ReadToEnd();
            migrationBuilder.Sql(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

This code finds all resources that end in “.sql” and runs each of them.

To make the SQL scripts embedded resources, you can just edit the .csproj file and make sure they are included like following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="SQL\{YourSqlFileName}.sql" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

And finally run update database command as usual

Comment: this is not the way. really, really bad idea

Comment: @pbordeaux Could you please elaborate