# C# reference .SQL file to populate datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have some really nice long SQL scripts that I want to run from a windows form application. I have gotten the following code to work but I have to put the actual SQL statement in it.

Is there anyway to reference a .sql file that contains my larger script?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you create a stored procedure in the database?

Comment: Sure, you can add the .SQL file as an embedded resource..

Comment: I embedded it as a resource.. can you please provide the syntax to reference it?

Comment: @user1887198 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379195/c-executing-a-sql-script-stored-as-a-resource - although you should really use stored procedures. That's best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention anything about these scripts or where they are located BUT if it is in a file that is shared or accessible you can do this:

```
string sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\\mysqlfile.sql");
```