# How to access sql file from Seed() in EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I have the following:

```
  string sproc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Stored Procedures/new_message.sql";
  context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sproc);
```

However the `sproc` path is invalid for some reason.  What is the proper way to access files in your project directory from the `Seed` Method of EF code-first migrations?

[image]

Comment: Are you intentionally giving path to `ExecuteSqlCommand` method?

Comment: If there were a method where you can pass a filename you can expect the name to be *ExecuteSqlComandFromFile*. But it is not and therefore you had to pass the command itself (read the file content and pass that content to the method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a SQL script stored as a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379195/executing-a-sql-script-stored-as-a-resource)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If those `.sql` files are stored as **embedded resources** in your assembly, then you can do something like this:

```
Assembly asy = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

Stream stm = asy.GetManifestResourceStream("yourAssembly.Stored_Procedures.new_message.sql");

if (stm != null)
{
    string sql = new StreamReader(stm).ReadToEnd();
    // now you have the SQL statements which you can execute 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
}
```

You may use this to determine the name of the resources from `Seed()` if needed:

```
Assembly asy = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string[] names = asy.GetManifestResourceNames();
throw new Exception(string.Join("", names));
```