# What is the best practice to create SQL script files?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

At work, we have multiple telegrams to communicate with a customer. Those telegrams are always different with each customer, but the logic, how we work with them is always the same. The data is sent to a table on our schema with other data for example like sent time and telegram type. We split it into a view to simplify it for development and testing purpose.

Example JSON:

```
{"Prop1": "Test"}
```

Example view script (using Oracle Enterprise):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test
AS
SELECT prop1
  FROM telegram
     , JSON_TABLE (
        telegram.json,
        '$' COLUMNS (
         prop1 PATH '$.Prop1'
        )
       )
```

My problem is now, that I do not know the correct or good way to create those view scripts with C#. Currently, I use a constant string with placeholders ({0}, {1}, ...) but they are getting really hard to maintain. I also read about T4, but it is only useable with Visual Studio. AFAIK we plan to move to .NET 5 and it looks like T4 is not available anymore and/or you cannot call the created C# classes in the code without some errors. I heard about Roslyn, too. Is it possible to create .txt/.sql instead of .cs files?
I hope I got all the information needed to answer this question. If I forgot some information, tell me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using EF? Is there any reason why you need to use view? In my current project (.Net6) we will just use tables, no view or SP. So I also wondering what everyone suggested as a best practice. We won't use view/SP because we want to keep DB migration simple. So we're using LINQ even for large data tables.

Comment: We use ADO.NET most of the time and sometimes EF. The codebase is pretty old, so the logic builds up on the views.

Comment: You forgot to mention the database. SQL, the language, doesn't support JSON. That's a product-specific feature. What are you trying to do? Expose all JSON properties as columns? What database product are you using? That's certainly not SQL Server syntax

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. We are using Oracle. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create .txt/.sql instead of .cs files?

Sure, you can add the .txt/.sql file to your project and set its build action to "Embedded Resource".

In your code, you can access the content of that resource with [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=net-6.0) or by [linking it to a resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1379195/87698). Afterwards, you can apply `String.Replace` or `String.Format` for placeholders, if required.

---

That having been said, you might want to consider storing your data as *relational data* in your database, instead of JSON text that needs to be parsed by a for *Every. Single. Query.* Not only will this allow you to get rid of your view, but it will improve performance and allow you to use indexes on relevant fields.